# Use Of patchValue in Reactive Forms with parent child routing

Tags: angular

I have a form with parent child routing .Once user has saved info ,the code will save that data to some db. On my home page ; I will be getting data from db in the grid form and on clicking EDIT ,my form should route user to edit the already saved form-data and update it. I have created home-page and respective routes . On clicking edit my code is navigating me to my form component but getting error on clicking child component (as I have not provided route for the same). Can some help me achieve this?

I want, once user clicked on edit it should directly route user to person-info with pre-filled data and if he wishes to go to person-job ; he should be able to see data in job as well.

[Existing Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmhdtx)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this if you want info & job route under edit too,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home' , component:HomePageComponent},
  {
    path: 'edit/:age' , component: PersonFormComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'info', component: PersonInfoComponent },
      { path: 'job', component: PersonJobComponent }]
  },
  {
    path: 'person',
    component: PersonFormComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'info', component: PersonInfoComponent },
      { path: 'job', component: PersonJobComponent }]
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Comment: I am more concerned with- how the data will flow here. And additionally with the array elements(not currently implemented)

Comment: use one route as person with optional parameter(age), if params has value, then show the record in info based on age else create new object to get personal detail.

Comment: @Shubham Karanjekar, additionally with the array elements ?

Comment: I am more solicitous over data.I don't know how the user will be able to see the data of the row once clicked on it. Also I want the user to be redirected to PersonInfoComponent not PersonFormComponent .Feel free to update my stackblitz